# Undefined method '[]' for nil class during test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, automated-tests

I'm learning how to write automated tests in rails and I'm running into a problem. Here's my test:

```
test "login invalido" do
    get new_usuario_path
    assert_template 'usuarios/new'
    post login_path, params: { sessao: { email: "", password: "" } }
    assert_template 'usuarios/new'
    assert_not flash.empty?
    get root_path
    assert flash.empty?
end
```

And here's the method in `login_path`:

```
def create
byebug
u = Usuario.find_by(email: params[:sessao][:email].downcase) #the error happens here
if u.present? && u.authenticate(params[:sessao][:password])
  puts "aqui"
else
    flash[:danger] = 'Ops! Email ou senha inválidos.'
    redirect_to new_usuario_path
end
end
```

edit: I marked the line where the error occurs above.

I'm trying to verify if the flash error message is displayed and doesn't linger during navigation (I'm using [this book](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/basic_login) as reference). I expected to get a failure in this test, but instead I get an error:

```
 1) Error:
LoginTest#test_login_invalido:
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
app/controllers/sessao_controller.rb:7:in `create'
test/integration/login_test.rb:7:in `block in <class:LoginTest>'
```

It seems that the `params` hash is incorrect, but when running the test with `byebug` I see that the hash is arriving correctly:

```
(byebug) params
{"params"=>{"sessao"=>{"email"=>"", "password"=>""}}, "controller"=>"sessao", "action"=>"create"}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `params` is method ?

Comment: No, params is a hash with parameters that will be passed to the `create` method and being used here: `u = Usuario.find_by(email: params[:sessao][:email].downcase)`

Comment: you dont send any parametters into create method.

Comment: Seems like `params[:sessao]` is nil `params[:sessao][:email]`

Comment: which one is line:7 ? in sessao_controller

Comment: @DeepakMahakale I thought so too, but running it with `byebug` it seems that `params` contains `{"params"=>{"sessao"=>{"email"=>"", "password"=>""}}`

Comment: @DeepakMahakale Sorry, I forgot to say it. Line 7 is this: `u = Usuario.find_by(email: params[:sessao][:email].downcase)`

Comment: Try `params["sessao"]["email"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The params you are passing is instance of class `Hash` not  `ActionController::Parameters`

So, either make the hash `.with_indifferent_access`

```
post login_path, params: { sessao: { email: "", password: "" } }.with_indifferent_access
```

Or

```
ActionController::Parameters.new({ sessao: { email: "", password: "" } })
```

Comment: Tried the `ActionController::Parameters.new({ sessao: { email: "", password: "" } })` line and it worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: @Tuma i think this fixed your issue coincidentally. you were accidentally nesting your params within a "param" key. changing your post to this would fix the problem too: `post login_path, sessao: { email: "", password: "" }`

Comment: That's true, leaving only the `sessao` hash also worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try params["sessao"]["email"].
I think in ruby :variable != "variable"

Comment: I tried changing it from symbol to string on the `create` method and on both the test and the method, but the error persists...

Comment: `byebug` points that both `params[:sessao]` and `params["sessao"]` are `nil`, but simply `params` shows the complete hash. Very strange.